# Textblock content not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm sorry if this is a repeat of another question, but I'm completely stumped and didn't see anything pertaining to my specific question.

```
class ErrorTicketDisplay
{
    public ErrorTicket[] tickArray1 = new ErrorTicket[1];
    internal ErrorTicket[] tickArray2 = new ErrorTicket[1];

    public ErrorTicketDisplay(List<ErrorTicket> tickets, int o)
    {
        tickArray1 = tickets.ToArray();

        String errorDisplayString = "";

        ErrorDisplay errorForm = new ErrorDisplay();

        MergeSort(o, tickArray1, 0, tickArray1.Length - 1);

        foreach (ErrorTicket tick in tickArray1)
        {
            errorDisplayString += tick.toString() + "\r\n";
            errorForm.errorBlock.Height += 16;

        }

        if (!errorDisplayString.Equals(""))
        {
            errorForm.errorBlock.Text = "Results:" + "\r\n";
            errorForm.errorBlock.Text += errorDisplayString;
        }

        else if (errorDisplayString.Equals(""))
        {
            errorForm.errorBlock.Text = "Results:" + "\r\n";
            errorForm.errorBlock.Text += "No Issue Tickets Found";
        }

        errorForm.Show();
    }
}
```

The ErrorDisplay object is a standard Wpf window and contains a textblock "errorBlock" to hold a string of results and a couple buttons. The issue is that, in either of the if statements, the content of the Textblock will be updated, but when it leaves the statement and I try to show the form, the content empties and I'm left with just a blank box and the buttons. Why is this happening, and how does one update the content of a textblock before showing it properly? I'm running Visual Studio 2013 if that makes any difference.

EDIT: Here's the xaml markup:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.UIWindows.ErrorDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ErrorDisplay" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="240" Margin="0,0,0,40">
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="292" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button x:Name="close" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="207,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonClick"/>
    <Button x:Name="newAudit" Content="New Audit" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="127,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonClick"/>
    <Button x:Name="errorCodes" Content="Error Codes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonClick"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: can you add your xaml markup for the form

Comment: "it leaves the statement ... the content empties" - what is "it" and what "statement" does it leave? Have you examined the value of `errorForm.errorBlock.Text` when the debugger stops on `errorForm.Show();`?

Comment: Are there any events of `ErrorDisplay` class that manipulate `errorBlock.Text`?

Comment: @Igor - "It" is the and the environment running through the code, and "statement" is either the if or else if statement that sets the content of the textblock. The content of Text before the debugger stops is a string value, and when it stops on .Show() the _complexContent and _textBlockCache are null and the _contentCache is the string value. And no, the only event in ErrorDisplay handles the button clicks.

Comment: you do better passing the errors to the Window constructor and setting the Windows values in the Loaded event.

Comment: @MarkHomer - I just tried what you suggested and it's still coming up with an empty text screen.

Comment: try setting the textblock text without the errorForm.errorBlock.Text += part

Comment: @MarkHomer - Yup. I built the string and passed it and the height of the box as arguments into ErrorDisplay's constructor, which ran InitializeComponent, then set the height of the box as errorBlock.Height = heightArg, and lastly set the text as errorBlock.Text = textArg.